# Add values to lookupmulti field in c#

Tags: development, lookup-column, multiple-values

I want to add values to a lookupmulti field with c#. the form shows the field correctly but my code just won't work:

```
SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["testlist"];
SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(someId);
SPFieldLookupValueCollection fieldValues = new SPFieldLookupValueCollection();
foreach(int id in itemIds) {
   fieldValues.Add(new SPFieldLookupValue {LookupId = id});
}
item["lookupmultifield"] = fieldValues;
```

The code above is not exactly my code, but it's how i thought it should work. 
FieldValues has 2 entries, but only the first is inserted in the lookupmulti field.
can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i wrote Mult="True" instead of Mult="TRUE"

I should not listen to VS 2010 intellisense

Answer (score 6):

here's a code fragment that's similar but 'list.Items.Add() & item.Update()' are missing from your code

```
SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["testlist"];  
SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();  
SPFieldLookupValueCollection fieldValues = new
SPFieldLookupValueCollection();

fieldValues.Add (new SPFieldLookupValue(1, "SomeValue1"));  // add other field values or in loop

item["lookupmultiField"] = fieldValues;
item.Update();
```

Comment: thanks, but i updated some other fields and updated after that.

Comment: Any Example with Linq?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but there are 2 constructors for SPFieldLookupValue class:

```
SPFieldLookupValue(String) // Initializes a new instance of the SPFieldLookupValue class that is based on the specified field value.
SPFieldLookupValue(Int32, String) // Initializes a new instance of the SPFieldLookupValue class that is based on the specified lookup identifier (ID) and value.
```

It looks like you should specify Id and Value of related objects...

Comment: thanks but I tried that already but same result

Comment: will post the solution when i can

Comment: Are you sure that you use correct Value? '<Field ID="x" Type="Lookup" List="x" ShowField="Title"...' you should use value of field that is set in ShowField property of list schema. In example above it is Item["Title"]