# How to set multiple values in sharepoint lookup field using c#

Tags: lookup-column

I want to set the multiple values in lookup column.
my string format is id#;id#;id#; but it is giving error.

Comment: What error do you get? And also can you please post the code you used. This will make easy for providing solution.

Comment: Read http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29491/add-values-to-lookupmulti-field-in-c

Comment: Ya I got  List<FieldLookupValue> branchLookupValueList = new List<FieldLookupValue>();
                string[] branchIds = userInformation.Branch_Name.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                foreach (var branchId in branchIds)
                {
                    FieldLookupValue LookupColBranch = new FieldLookupValue();
                    LookupColBranch.LookupId = Convert.ToInt32(branchId);
                    branchLookupValueList.Add(LookupColBranch);
                }
                NewItem["BranchName"] = branchLookupValueList;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this below code:

```
String [] idsCol = id.split("#;");       //id = your string "id#;id#;id#;"
SPFieldLookupValueCollection fieldValues = new SPFieldLookupValueCollection();
foreach(string s in idsCol)
{
    fieldValues.Add(new SPFieldLookupValue{LookupId=(Convert.ToInt32(s))});
}
SPListItem newItem = list.Items.Add();   //list = your desired list object
newItem["Your column name"] = fieldValues;
newItem.Update();
```

Comment: Please do upvote answer, if it is helpful to you:)

Answer (score 2):

```
 List<FieldLookupValue> branchLookupValueList = new List<FieldLookupValue>();
                string[] branchIds = userInformation.Branch_Name.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                foreach (var branchId in branchIds)
                {
                    FieldLookupValue LookupColBranch = new FieldLookupValue();
                    LookupColBranch.LookupId = Convert.ToInt32(branchId);
                    branchLookupValueList.Add(LookupColBranch);
                }
                NewItem["BranchName"] = branchLookupValueList;
```