# How to set multi lookup field in C# CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, error

I'm having trouble setting multi lookup field. I found this example:

[Update a LookupMulti Column value in SharePoint using Client Object Model C#](https://piyushksingh.com/2014/01/19/update-a-lookupmulti-column-value-in-sharepoint-using-client-object-model-c/) and 
[Setting a SharePoint Multi-value Lookup Field value using PowerShell and CSOM](https://platinumdogs.me/2014/11/05/setting-a-sharepoint-multi-value-lookup-field-value-using-powershell-and-csom/)

And also this:
[Add values to lookupmulti field in c#](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29491/add-values-to-lookupmulti-field-in-c), but its not using CSOM.

The code I have is this:

```
                ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                SP.ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);

                FieldLookupValue[] arr = new FieldLookupValue[1];
                FieldLookupValue lvItem = new FieldLookupValue();
                lvItem.LookupId = 7;
                arr[0] = lvItem;

                oListItem["prjIBusers"] = arr;

                oListItem.Update();

                context.ExecuteQuery();
```

But it throws the following error at `ExecuteQuery()`

```
  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Unknown Error
  Source=Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream responseStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder sb)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var lookupValues = new ArrayList();            
var lookupValue = new FieldLookupValue { LookupId = 7 };
lookupValues.Add(lookupValue);
//var lookupValue1 = new FieldLookupValue { LookupId = 5 };
//lookupValues.Add(lookupValue1);
oListItem["prjIBusers"] = lookupValues.ToArray();
oListItem.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

**OR**:

Don't build an array of `SP.FieldLookupValue`, instead save multiple lookup values to string as mentioned here:

[SharePoint 2013: How to update multi-value lookup field using JavaScript CSOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622272/sharepoint-2013-how-to-update-multi-value-lookup-field-using-javascript-csom).

Comment: If that doesn't work then try using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622272/sharepoint-2013-how-to-update-multi-value-lookup-field-using-javascript-csom).

Comment: This did not work, same error, but using a string value did, ty, could you please modify the answer so I could accept it

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I have updated my answer.